How to integrate $\int_{0}^{1}[x^{2}+x+2]dx$ ? $[.]=$ G.I.F.
How to integrate $$\int_{0}^{1}[x^{2}+x+2]dx$$ ? Here, $[.]$ denotes Greatest Integer Function
I searched the answer in desmos and the value is $2.38$
But I am getting the answer to be $2.4$
I broke the interval $(0,1)$ in two different intervals. Those intervals are: $(0,0.6);(0.6,1)$
That is I wrote the integral to be
$$\int_{0}^{0.6}[x^{2}+x+2]dx+\int_{0.6}^{1}[x^{2}+x+2]dx$$
Now in the interval $(0,0.6)$ the value of $[x^{2}+x+2]$ is $2$ and for the interval $(0.6,1)$ the value of $[x^{2}+x+2]$ is $3$.
Therefore the result of the integral $$\int_{0}^{1}[x^{2}+x+2]dx$$ is $2(0.6-0)+3(1-0.6)$ which results in $2.4$
Please clear me that where I am making the mistake.

“for the interval $(0.6,1)$ the value of $[x^{2}+x+2]$ is $3$" This is wrong. For instance, $0.61^2+0.61+2=2.9821$

Did you just guess the value $0.6$ to split the interval?

@BoweiTang the floor value of $[x^{2}+x+2]$ is $3$ for the interval $(0.6,1)$

No. I didn't guess that value @jjagmath

Ok, so why there's no explanation at all on where that value came from?

No, the value is not $3$ in the interval $(0.6,1)$. Bowei Tang already gave you a counterexample.


Usually if an integral contains greatest integer function, we draw a graph for better clarity;
So by using $({-b \over 2a},{-D \over 4a})$, find the vertex of the quadratic
Then use $f(0)$, $f(1)$ and $f(x)=3$ to find the required critical points.
That is where $x= {-1+\sqrt{5}\over2}$ comes (not $0.6$)
Finally find area of shaded portion.

The answer is $\frac{7}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} \approx 2.381966\dots$
You have the right idea, and you'd get the right answer if you replace $0.6$ with the precise point where the graph of $y=x^2+x+2$ crosses $y=3$, which is $x=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$.
Edit: the value of $x$ comes from solving $x^2+x+2=3$, eg by the quadratic formula $$x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4(1)(-1)}}{2} \approx 0.618\dots$$

How you found $x=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ ?@tkw
